# RxJava2: How to get a dedicated background thread for work

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Is it possible to schedule work on a dedicated background thread? I need to ensure the work is done in serial, but also it must be done on the background.

Basically - is there a combination of the `trampoline` and `io` schedulers out there?

Comment: Why not just use a ThreadPool with a single Thread?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, great! `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` and then when I want to use it with RxJava, `subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(singleThreadExecutor))`  if you want to make this an answer I will gladly accept it!

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment, in case anyone else is reading this - I think it'd be more correct to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a ThreadPool with only one Thread.

RxJava2 provides such a standard Scheduler:

```
Schedulers.single()
```

Or use the Factory method:

```
Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
```